# Note Board notes not visible to all?

Tags: 2010, social-note

This is SP2010. I've started using the Note Board Web Part, but have found that it does *not* display all the notes left by all the users; which is pretty maddening. What I was wrongly asserting it did was to display all notes that people left, in a typical "Comments" thread like you'd see on a news website, or perhaps like a Facebook discussion.

So, is there a way to get the Note Board Web Part to display all the notes from all users?

Comment: Why do you think that not all comments are displayed? User can also mark comments as private and those won't be displayed naturally.

Comment: Both my coworker and I have witnessed this behavior with the NBWP. We took turns plugging notes on the board and refreshing the page. They do not all show up. We are not marking the notes as private, nor have we tweaked any sort of web part settings to filter or limit results to current user.

Comment: @AlanM - You write that you are refreshing the board. Perhaps this is a caching issue.

Comment: after posting the comments, no body can see it? is their any limit on number of comment display on the page? check the web part properties. what about all user permissions?

Comment: We did all that. Now fwiw, the subsite itself containing the page with the NBWP on it is limited-access. The people viewing the page of course have rights to do so, but it's that NBWP which is refusing to display all the notes.

Comment: While I cannot confirm it right now, I believe the culprit is my failing to fill in the "Custom Properties > URL For Note" field in the Edit Web Part area. Apparently if you leave this blank, Things Work Badly.